# Cannot set Crypto Provider for Spring CryptoFactoryBean

Tags: java, apache, spring-boot, wss4j

When trying to set the crypto provider for an instance of Spring Boot's `CryptoFactoryBean`, you are required to use a class that extends the Apache `Crypto` class. However, none of the current Apache WSS4J crypto providers actually extend the `Crypto` class - they extend `CryptoBase`, which implements `Crypto`. In Eclipse, the following code will throw an error:

```
    @Bean
    public CryptoFactoryBean serverKeyStoreCryptoFactoryBean() throws IOException {

        CryptoFactoryBean cryptoFactoryBean = new CryptoFactoryBean();
        try {
            cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStoreLocation(new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"));
            cryptoFactoryBean.setKeyStorePassword(keyStorePassword);
            cryptoFactoryBean.setCryptoProvider(new Merlin());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Crypto Factory Bean: unable to set the keystore location or password", e);
        }

        return cryptoFactoryBean;
    }
```

The error says that because the `Merlin` class doesn't extend the `Crypto` class, it cannot be used as the crypto provider, despite being created for and implementing the `Crypto` class.

Is there a factory that I need to create to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When setting the crypto provider, you need to actually pass in the class itself. E.g., `cryptoFactoryBean.setCryptoProvider(Merlin.class);`